# Modal pop up not showing in ASP.NET Core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, asp.net-core-5.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC  application, and i'm trying to display a bootstrap modal popup. I used the code below:

Index.cshtml:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEmp">
    Ajouter
</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
    ...
</table>
```

_EmployeePartialView.cshtml:

```
@model Employee

<div class="modal fade" id="addEmp" aria-labelledby="addEmpLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="addEmpLabel">Employee</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">                    
                        <form asp-action="Create">
                            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label asp-for="Profession" class="control-label"></label>
                                <input asp-for="Profession" class="form-control" />
                                <span asp-validation-for="Profession" class="text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                   
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EmployeeController:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Employee> emp = _dbcontext.Employees.ToList();
        return View(emp);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        return PartialView("_EmployeePartialView", emp);
    }
```

But when i click on the button the modal popup is not showing without any errors. any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Please firstly check if the partial view correctly load to your html page. You can F12 and check the `Elements` panel in browser.

2.Then please check your bootstrap version,because if you use **Bootstrap v 5.0**, it used `data-bs-target` instead of `data-target`.

3.Be sure the partial view locates in `Views/Shared/` or `Views/Employee/` folder.

Not sure how do you render the partial view, below I share two ways to render the partial view.

Use **html helper to display** the partial view:

```
@model List<Employee>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEmp">
    Ajouter
</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
     //...
</table>

@await Html.PartialAsync("_EmployeePartialView", new Employee())
```

Use **ajax to call** `Create` **action to display** the partial view:

```
@model List<Employee>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addEmp">
    Ajouter
</button>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
</table>
<div id="display">

</div>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/Employee/Create",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#display").html(data);

                }
            })
        })
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I was forgetting to render the partial view. Thank you very much i really appreciate your help.